# How to reset coordinates into an Ajax call after having initialized a map?

Tags: json, ajax, api, leaflet, openstreetmap

I inserted a map on my webpage by using the Leaflet library. What I want to do is to show a map zoomed on a specific region according to which city the user types into a text field.

I firstly initialized my map on my JS file:

```
function initMaps(){

    map = L.map('leaflet').setView([0, 0], 13);

    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 18,
        'attribution': 'Map data © <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);

}
```

My javascript code also has an Ajax call. 
What I want to do now is to reset the coordinates on the Ajax call.
I wrote the following:

```
var readCoordinates = function(){

    $.ajax({
        url: "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=" + encodeURIComponent($("#inlineFormInputCitta").val()) + "+Italy&format=geocodejson",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {

            setTimeout(function () {

                for (let i = 0; i < data.features.length; i++) {
                    let coordinate = data.features[i].geometry.coordinates;   

                    console.log(coordinate);

                    map.setView(coordinate, 13);

                    console.log("ajax and for loop have been activated");
                    console.log(coordinate.geometry.coordinates);
                };
                $("#ristoranti").prop("disabled", false);

            }, 1000);
        }
    });

};
```

The API I'm referring to in the URL is the following: https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=Roma%20Italy&format=geocodejson

What I did is trying to reset the coordinates here: `map.setView(coordinate, 13);`

after having cycled the elements in the JSON object, see the following:

```
for (let i = 0; i < data.features.length; i++) {
                    let coordinate = data.features[i].geometry.coordinates;
```

I may display several coordinates in the console, see the following:

[image: Too many coordinates]

That's because in the JSON file I get through the API request there are several:

[image]

The result of this is the following map, which isn't zoomed anywhere:

[image: resulting map]

Which coordinates should I take in order to display that specific region?

- - - EDIT - - -

I changed the code because I'm trying to get a specific subobject, i.e. the one in the screen below (which has "type" = "city"):

[image: subobject of the JSON file in the API request]

The new snippet is the one below, where I add an *if statement*:

```
var readCoordinates = function(){

    $.ajax({
        url: "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=" + encodeURIComponent($("#inlineFormInputCitta").val()) + "+Italy&format=geocodejson",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {

            setTimeout(function() {

                for (let i = 0; i < data.features.length; i++) {

                    debugger;    

                    let type = data.features[i].properties.geocoding.type;

                    if(  $(type).val() === "city") {

                    let coordinate = data.features[i].geometry.coordinates;

                    let lng = coordinate[0];

                    let lat = coordinate[1];

                      map.setView([lng, lat], 13);

                    console.log("ajax and for loop have been activated");
                    console.log(coordinate);}
                };

                $("#ristoranti").prop("disabled", false);

            }, 1000);
        }
    });

};
```

I'm doing the debugger and get many undefined values:

[image: type is undefined]
[image: feature is not defined]
[image: properties is not defined]
[image: geocoding is not defined]
[image: type is undefined]

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like that:

```
if (typeof data.features[0] !== 'undefined') {
    let coordinate = data.features[0].geometry.coordinates;
    var latlng = L.latLng(coordinate.reverse());
    map.flyTo(latlng, 12)
}
```

1. Be sure to have something in your array
2. Get data from the first item since it should be the correct one in most case
3. Create a `latlng` with those coordinates. Be careful, sometime you need to reverse the array to have the correct position.
4. Use `flyTo` to have a smooth transition to your coordinates. 12 is the zoom level

You don't need to loop over the data since you need only one position. You can replace the `for` with that.

Answer (score 1):

You're having two problems here:

- The response from the Nominatim API is returning several search results, each of them in one GeoJSON `Feature` inside the response `FeatureCollection`. It's up to you to choose which search result you want to focus in the map (the first?), or let the user do so.
- [You're not aware that GeoJSON uses longitude-latitude (or x-y) coordinates, whereas Leaflet uses latitude-longitude (or y-x)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35984328)