# Error while interpolating way points with turf.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, leaflet, gis, turfjs

[image]

I'm working with leaflet, node and turf.js for gis calculations. I'm trying to plot a road on a map with points every 200 meters.

On the client page (inside the script tag) I have the following:

```
  (async function buildMap(params) {
    const o = await getGeoJSONArr();
    console.log('getGeoJSONArr ',o);
    const polyline1 = o.jsonArr;
    const centerCoords = o.reversedCoords;
    L.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
      attribution:
        'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
      maxZoom: 18,
    }).addTo(mymap);

    mymap.setView(centerCoords, 13);

    console.log("polyline1 ", polyline1);

    const reversedPolyLine1 = polyline1.map((coord) => coord.reverse());

    // have to reverse openstreetmap lat/long for leaflet

    L.polyline(reversedPolyLine1, { color: "blue" }).addTo(mymap);

    var road = turf.lineString(reversedPolyLine1);

    const roadLength = turf.length(road, {
      units: "meters",
    });
    console.log("RL ", roadLength);

    let pointList = [];
    for (let distance = 0; distance < roadLength; distance += 200) {
      const point = turf.along(road, distance, { units: "meters" });
      console.log('point ',point);
      pointList.push(point.geometry.coordinates);
    }
    console.log('pointlist ',pointList);
    L.polyline(pointList, { color: 'red' }).addTo(mymap);

  })();
```

I'm working in arizona which has approximately (31.xx, -112.xx) latitude/longitude. You can see that the first point looks correct, but the remainder of the 'interpolated' points show up as:

31.x,-67.x , which is nowhere near Arizona. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35983078/leaflet-swap-the-coordinates-when-use-geojson . Note that Turf relies on GeoJSON exclusively.

Comment: @IvanSanchez, I appreciate the comment, but unless I'm missing something this is not about just flipping long and lat (I'm already dealing with this in the code sample). If so the numbers would be going from 31.x, -112.y to -112.y, 31.x - that's not happening here

Comment: Since 67 is (about) half of 112, I suspect you're dealing with a [Null Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Island)-like problem here. Note that you're passing lat-lng coordinates to `turf.linestring`, so it's possible that Turf is interpreting a latitude outside of the (-90,90) range as zero.